# which os supports which compilers

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, compiler-construction

I'm working on a paper for school and I was wondering which compilers are supported by which operating systems.

I know Mac supports C and C++ (I know they're not that different but to me they are 2 different languages)

I was wondering which compilers/languages are supported by windows, which by Ubuntu and which by Mac.

Sorry for asking a straight question but i think there's people who know this straight away.

thanks

Comment: The usual question is "which OSs are supported by which compilers", since the operating system is the platform on which the compiler runs. GCC, for example, supports a large number of architectures and operating systems. See the list (in a rather cryptic chart) here: http://gcc.gnu.org/backends.html and the list of languages implemented here: http://gcc.gnu.org/frontends.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Support" is a relative term here.  At one extreme, I think if you have a computer with just about any version of Linux installed (Ubuntu is just one variety), if that version of the O/S isn't too stripped-down you will already have a compiler for C and C++ .  If you just installed Windows, however (or got a new Windows computer from the factory), you almost certainly have no C or C++ compiler there and must obtain and install one.  (There are various choices.)  So Windows does not "support" C and C++ as well as Linux does, in that sense.

At the other extreme, just about any compilable language can be compiled on any of those three platforms ... if you are willing and able to write your own compiler.

In between those two extremes, you would have to ask whether someone anywhere has already written a compiler for that language on that platform, and whether you can obtain a copy of that compiler.  Most of these are "third-party" software packages, so knowing which ones exist is partly a function of how well the compilers have been advertised.  Even the Wikipedia page on this topic says its list may be incomplete.  On the other hand, it's likely you have never heard of most of the languages that are listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a list of compilers and OS support here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers